# Rails 3.1 all assets being included in layout file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am in development mode, I have 6 controllers, I notice there is a lot of CSS files and JS files being included, is this necessary? Can I, or should I just tell the helpers to include the specified files I need for my app?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default behavior by specifying in the application.js/css which files to include by using the require/require_tree commands.

Answer (score 1):

As @sailor said, you can override the default behavior.  It's worth knowing, however, that once you run `rake assets:precompile` and deploy your application, all of your css and js will be compiled into one file for you.  Having them all separate in your development environment is just for the ease in debugging your application.